# ConTeXt - escape percent sign in externalfigure

Tags: context, includegraphics, catcodes

This fails during typesetting:

```
{\externalfigure[https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41rVft84o%2BL._SX384_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg][book]}{}
```

This typesets, but the image doesn't display (it shows one of those grey placeholder boxes).

```
{\externalfigure[https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41rVft84o\%2BL._SX384_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg][book]}{}
```

presumably the percent sign is the problem in both, for different reasons.

What's the right way to deal with special characters in a url of an `externalfigure` in context?

### Further info

#### Input

https://pastebin.com/PkW93yf6

#### Log

https://pastebin.com/1eRdEgKm

#### Screenshots

As recommended in the comments, I tried this:

```
{\externalfigure[https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41rVft84o\textpercent2BL._SX384_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg][vhs]}{}
```

but still get the grey box:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Use `\letterpecent` or `\textpercent` to get a `%` which works in arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried both but still get a grey box (added a screenshot). Any idea why?

Comment: I get a image when I use `\letterpercent`.

Comment: Hmmmm, so there's something wrong with my environment (I just added a screenshot of using `\letterpercent` too). I'm not sure if it is relevant but I'm using `Context (Luatex)` rather than `Context` in TexShop's type setter. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: What url did you try with?

Comment: I used the URL from your snippet but without a working minimal example or the log file from it it impossible to tell what's wrong.

Comment: Added example and log to OP

Comment: Can you add `\enabletrackers[graphics.*]` at the begin of your example and show the resulting log file, the default output doesn't show enough information.

Comment: More verbose logging pasted here: https://pastebin.com/PWr6YHUe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What's the right way to deal with special characters in a url of an externalfigure in context?

`\asciimode`, which changes the catcode table so that everything other than `\`, `{`, and `}` has letter catcode.

```
\starttext
\startasciimode    
{\externalfigure[https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41rVft84o%2BL._SX384_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg][book]}{}
\stopasciimode
\stoptext
```

Comment: I haven't had time to try this but will temporarily mark it as correct

Comment: 3 years on I tried it and it din't have any effect. Maybe my issue is not related to special characters. Other urls work fine.

Comment: Works fine with LMTX version `2023.07.18` at my end.